Why do I get the STOMP client error: Server has gone away?
I am trying to send a STOMP message, but it always fails with the error:
Error: Server has gone away

This is the code of the push implementation:
  sendMessage(destination: string, message: string): void {
    this.stompClient.publish(destination, message);
  }

I am using the NodeJS(with TS) library "stomp-client": "^0.9.0" in order to connect to the ActiveMQ servers.
I can confirm that the connection initially is successfully made as I receive the session id of the connection on connect() callback. The way I connect is described below:
  this.stompClient = new StompClient(url, port, username, password);
  ...
  connect(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.stompClient.connect(
        (sessionId: string) => {
          console.log(
            `Producer connected to ActiveMQ with session ID: ${sessionId}`,
          );
          resolve();
        },
        (error: Error) => {
          console.error("Error connecting to ActiveMQ producer:", error);
          reject(error);
        },
      );
    });
  }

I can't wrap my head around why I can't publish anything right now. I'm open to any suggestions, tips, advice, etc.

It could be also because of the stomp client, I was taking that into consideration as well. As for the ActiveMQ version I use, it's 5.17.1

Here's the line in the client that logs Server has gone away.

Is it possible that the connection was established but authorization failed (i.e. user didn't have permission to send a message to that destination)?

I don't have any authorization mechanisms implemented on these ActiveMQ servers. The ActiveMQ I use locally is something I just freshly installed. The only thing I was thinking about was that maybe because I'm using queues to send messages and not topics, the queues might have not been created due to the fresh install I did. But I'm not sure about that anymore now because I think they should be automatically created, like the topics.
